# Buying Grenth's hood?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I personally feel as though `Grenth's Hood` is one of the coolest helms in the game.

Is there any way of knowing when it will be on the `Gem Store` again?

Comment: You mean the Gem Store?

Comment: Oops, i'll edit that @Affine

Comment: edited. @Affine

Comment: Bump to notify you. See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have insider knowledge at Arenanet, there's no way of knowing when they'll bring items back to the gem store.

That being said, the [Grenth Hood Skin](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Grenth_Hood_Skin) was first made available in the gem store for Wintersday 2013, so the most likely time for it to return would be Wintersday 2014. They may offer it sooner, and there's no guarantee they'll offer it again at all, but you'll probably be able to get it December 2014.

Update: The Grenth Hood was available for 500 gems in the gem store, as part of the [second anniversary 10-day sale](https://www.guildwars2.com/en/news/welcome-to-the-second-anniversary-10-day-sale/).